# reading facebook token in url, storing in cookie, echoing in file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I have a multi -part process

step 1:on page.php I evoke a facebook pop-up authentication window with the URI going to **page2.php**

> https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=http://domain.com/page2.php?-Your+Special+Token+1170-&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&scope=publish_stream

on **page2.php** I want to process this token by reading it from the url and storing it as a cookie

```
<?php

  session_start(); 

 if ( empty($tkn) ) { ?>
<script>
(function () {
  try {
    var q = location.href.split('#');
    var a = q[1];
    var q2 = a.split('=');
    var a2 = q2[1];
    var q3 = a2.split('&');
    var a3 = q3[0];
    setTimeout(function () {
        top.location.replace('http://domain.com/cookie.php?tkn=' + a3);
    }, 200);
} catch (e) {
    top.location.replace('http://domain.com/cookie.php?retry=1&tk=broken_' + encodeURI(e.message));
}
})()
</script><? } else {



    print $_GET['tkn'];


}


  $_SESSION['tkn'] = $tkn;

$tkn = $_POST["tkn"];

if(isset($tkn)) {

    setcookie("tkn", $tkn);
    echo "success";
}

?>
```

**page.php** detects the cookie and echoes out the token $tkn and reloads the page

```
<?php
        session_start();

    ?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.post('page2.php',{tkn: tkn}, function(data){ 
    if(data=='success'){
        location.reload(true)
    }
 });
</script>

<?php echo $tkn; ?>
```

the problem is I cant get any of this to work. The popup goes into an infinite error loop and nothing is refreshed or echoed.

Comment: Looks like you get a loop because your javascript keeps reloading the page once the ajax post requests returns success. I think you should execute the post request only if the cookie has not been set yet.

Comment: After some modification I was able to echo $tkn on page1.php after manually refreshing it but how to do with ajax?

Comment: The problem is your ajax call will execute all the time, even if the $tkn is set, therefore reloading the page over and over. What you should do is wrap your ajax call into a PHP if(!$tkn){} condition, so it only executes the ajax when the variable is not yet set.